# Using a4j:poll, how can I get it to rescan when the page is rendered?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I use a a4j:poll tag to update my status page every 5 seconds. This page displays the jobs running for a particular user. There is also a superuser who can jump between users.

```
<a4j:poll actionListener="#{searcher.checkStatus}" interval="5000" render="queueInfo,pg" id="poll"/>
```

When QA noticed that when the superuser changed users and then displayed the status page, the status for the last user was shown until the 5 seconds were up and the page updated to the correct user. So I added the immediate="true" attribute to the poller, thinking this would update when the page was displayed. (queueInfo is the outputText that shows the size of the queue. pg is the dataTable that displays the jobs that are queued.)

```
<a4j:poll actionListener="#{searcher.checkStatus}" immediate="true" interval="5000" render="queueInfo,pg" id="poll"/>
```

This didn't fix the problem. The status page still displays the old page for 5 seconds and then updates.

Anyone have ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/vdldoc/):

> immediate - Flag indicating that, if this component is activated by the user, notifications should be delivered to interested listeners and actions immediately (that is, during Apply Request Values phase) rather than waiting until Invoke Application phase.

---

You'll have to change the interval manually, start the polling and reset it, e.g.:

```
<a4j:ajax oncomplete="#{rich:component('poll')}.interval = 100; #{rich:component('poll')}.startPoll(); #{rich:component('poll')}.interval = 5000;" … />
```

Comment: Tricky. I'll try it.

Comment: What would be an appropriate element to add the a4j:ajax to? Not the poller, right?

Comment: Whatever you're using to switch the user, if it's an ajax component you can just put the `oncomplete` on it.

Comment: I discovered that the easiest way to get this done was added a list.clear(); to searcher.runSearch which calls this page. That clears the progress bars. Thanks for your help. It led me in interesting directions.